# Get Username of the Computer to know who uses the application on a local network in .NET

Tags: .net, web-applications, iis-7, localhost

How to get username of the computer (user account) for a .NET application to use it for log table of the application. So if the application has multiple users on the LAN, I can understand who did what by looking at the log table. I can get machine name but I need user name of the computer because multiple users can use one computer with their own user accounts.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string user = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) class you can use, it has the Username property which shows the windows user account name